# how to share sessions between independent tomcat instances

Tags: session, tomcat, grails

I have several tomcat instances running in physically independent machines.

I want to configure the tomcat to share sessions between this instances.

I have tried to configure org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html. But I only see the session file when I shutdown the tomcat instances and I don't know if the instances are sharing this session. I think not. Because It doesn't make sense if tomcat writes down the session only on shutdown.

The other thing that I found is the [cluster-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html) but I can't do that couse the machines can't see eachother. They only shares a storage path to use.

Other thing that I think I can do is to implement a [manager](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/Manager.html) but it seems a litle bit tricky.

I have to add that I am using tomcat for deploying grails war files and I am using the grails session. I thing it has something to do with Spring

So, the question is: What is the best thing you think I can do to accomplish more effectibly the task? Or maybe I am missing something? Can you give me any pointer?

Comment: why do you need to share the sessions at the application server level? I guess what I am asking can you solve your problem with sticky sessions?

Comment: I think you are talking about configure a cluster where the tomcat instances see eachother. I can't do that becouse the topology is diferent. In the past we develop our own session manager. This one share sessions in a storage. But now we want to use some session configuration in a server level.

Comment: No, sticky sessions are when the upstream load-balancer remembers which machine had which session then reroutes the user to the machine that has his/her session. Aaron is asking why you even need to share the sessions in the first place. Are you wanting to do this for failover purposes?

Comment: @javid thanks, yes I am suggesting damian provide more information on what problem he is trying to solve first, then maybe he can get better responses

Comment: Ok, sorry for my ignorance. What I am trying to do is to save some data in session, then redirect to a login server, who in a success scenario it redirects to my servers. And my concern is what happend if the load balancer redirects the request to the server that doesn't previously saved the needed data in session. Maybe sticky session is what I need. So: can I configure sticky session in a non tomcat-cluster enviromnent? thanks in advance

Comment: Also I am not using tomcat for load balancing either. I am using F5 bigip

Comment: Sorry: last comment. I would be good to configure shared sessions for failover also. Is another MUST to achieve. kill two birds with one stone maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the F5 Big IP doing the load balancing in front of the tomcat servers, so it will handle the [sessionID for you](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/features/articles/configure_big_ip.jsp) by sending you back to the correct Tomcat server. Use the `sticky-round-robin` algorithm.

As per the usecase in your comments -

> What I am trying to do is to save some
>   data in session, then redirect to a
>   login server, who in a success
>   scenario it redirects to my servers.
>   And my concern is what happend if the
>   load balancer redirects the request to
>   the server that doesn't previously
>   saved the needed data in session.
>   Maybe sticky session is what I need.
>   So: can I configure sticky session in
>   a non tomcat-cluster enviromnent?

At the successful login - you redirect back first to the BigIP. It will pick up the sessionID from the browser. It will send you to the correct Tomcat and you should be able to retrieve the session data.

If not, looks like you need to store the "sessionID" itself against some "user Id" in a database but thats a bad design. I think the former should work

Comment: @damian: Session failover will also be done by the Big IP in this case.

Comment: @damian: The article I linked shows how failover can be verified in the same configuration. Try it.